# CSS Scrollable aspect-ratio

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I have a `display: grid` div that contains elements.
These elements should be placed automatically as rows of elements, with a 1 / 1 aspect ratio so the parent should be scrollable.

Let's say I have 32 items, and I want them to show as 4 row of 8 items.

The items' width are shrinked to not overflow the parent, but I want them to overflow if needed.

[image]

Here is the parent CSS :

```css
display: grid;
gap: 10px;
padding: 20px;
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

and the items CSS

```css
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
```

It works just well if I explicitly add `width` or `height` to the children, but I want them to grow automatically.

CodePen : https://codepen.io/dbenfouzari/pen/GRmdVze?editors=1100
Try to resize the window to a smaller width to see it no working.

Thanks !

Comment: It works fine if I add explicit width to the child eg `width: 200px`.

Comment: You can also set a minmax() value to your grid-template-columns . it has at least to be able to hold the text under the icone without overflowing and can grow a bit on wider screens : possible example with clamp() helping out https://jsfiddle.net/apntLum8/2

Comment: Thanks for your reply @G-Cyrillus. But using `minmax()` assumes I know what's inside the divs, and I don't know.

I'm creating a component that can automatically layout the children.

And on your example, you inversed what I originally want : you creating 8 columns where I want 4 rows

Comment: Would you have some code to share demonstrating your issue ? the grid is usually first set then content is dispatch inside the cells . You are trying to make it work the other way. and rescale everything from the content and keep the aspect-ratio too . it's going to overflow really easily. Give us more details :)

Comment: My code is really what I gave in my question.

If you want to play with a CodePen : https://codepen.io/dbenfouzari/pen/GRmdVze?editors=1100

As you can see it works pretty well, but if you resize it's broken.

Comment: When you say you want them to "overflow", do you mean a) overflow the row to the right, or b) wrap the items onto the next line, or c) overflow the contents of each item to maintain the aspect ratio ?

Comment: Thanks for the pen .  i just noticed its drawn column by column, just updated the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/apntLum8/3/ i'll be back later and will take a look at your pen to match your structure

Comment: overflowing out of  item, the cell it stands inside the grid (constrain by the ratio applied), but that was on a row layout , i realized that you look for a column layout ;)

Comment: Hi @DavidCallanan, I want answer a: overflow the row on the right. Let's admit my window is 500px wide. And an item is 100px height. With 1/1 aspect ratio it should be 100px width, and with 8 items it should overflow 300px on the right.

Comment: @DonovanBENFOUZARI Ok. I have to think about whether that is possible to achieve.

Comment: hello, so from my last fidlle, using the minimal CSS required, `overflow` on the parent and `min-width:max-content;`  on the children, you have something starting to look alike your requirement :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxdzGKW but all items have the same average amount of content

Comment: Yeah it works fine when all items have same amount of content ! But IMO it should be okay. When you want to display a grid of items, you know that the content of each grid item should be similar.

So thanks @G-Cyrillus, it should work well now

Comment: I got another problem with this... Spacing (gap) is inconsistent if the first columns...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @G-Cyrillus answer, I finally get it to work simply by adding `overflow: auto;` on the parent wrapper and `min-width: max-content;` on each child !